# What is the rule? when do i use $(this) and when is "this" enough?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that `$(this)` results in a jQuery object, but i often see (especieally in jQuery plugins) the use of `return this.whatever` what is the general rule?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what `this` refers to.

Inside an event handler function `this` refers to the HTML element the event is raised from. To perform jQuery operations on the element, you use `$(this)` to wrap the HTML element.

`this` in the scope of a plugin method refers to the jQuery selection object itself. Additionally, in plugins the jQuery method `each` is used to perform a function to each element in a jQuery selection. This is often the way plugins are written to provide a new method:

```
jQuery.fn.alertClasses = function()
{
    // "this" refers to the jQuery object, returned by $(...)
    if(this[0] === undefined)
        return this;

    this.each(function() { 
        // "this" now refers to an HTML element in the jQuery object
        alert(this.className)
    });

    // "this" refers to the jQuery object again
    return this;
}
```

In short, it's all about the context of the method. The jQuery documentation explains this concept whenever you're looking at methods which change the value of `this`.

Comment: Isn't the check for `undefined` unnecessary here?  I'd imagine that `each()` already knows how to handle empty "sets."  In fact, I think you can just do `return this.each(function () { ... });`.

Comment: Indeed, I'd wager it's not necessary, but it is how many plugins are written (presumably as some sort of "optimization") and it made for a good illustrative case.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$(this)` when you want to use JQuery functionality on 'this'.

Use 'this' when you don't want to use JQuery functionality on 'this'.

Answer (score 3):

`$(this)` gives you `this` wrapped in jQuery. `$($(this))` is the same as `$(this)` and therefore the extra call to `$` is unnecessary in that case.

The answer is that it depends on the situation. In a lot of plugins, you call the plugin method on a jQuery object, which makes `this` already wrapped in jQuery!

Answer (score 2):

`$(this)` adds the extra JQuery "sugar" to the element and then returns it. So the rule is simply that you only need to use `$(this)` if you want to call JQuery methods on it, and it hasn't already been passed through `$(..)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this)` if you need to access your Object as a jQuery Object. If you're referring to internal properties of your Object that you don't need jQuery for, just use `this`

Answer (score 1):

As you noted:

$(this) -- returns jQuery object

this    -- returns DOM object

this.whatever will return an attribute/function of the DOM object

$(this).whatever will return an attribute/function of the jQuery object

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this)` when jQuery offers a better interface for the functionality you need (which is most of the time for DOM manipulation).

I recommend using `this` when you have to (when there's no jQuery equivalent), or when the basic interface is simpler, like calling  `form.submit()` rather than `$('form').trigger('submit')`.